# triggering event from default sequence to activate another sequence in test env

Tags: uvm

I have a default sequence set in the test (uvm_test) as:
 uvm_config_db#(uvm_object_wrapper)::set(this, "sve.vs.main_phase", "default_sequence",main_vseq_c::type_id::get());

Unfortunately There is another sequence in the test_env which is being activated also on main_phase. called 'seq_seq_c'

How can I synchronize between the sequences? Can I use events in 'main_vseq_c' to trigger 'seq_seq_c'? and I can, how do I execute this?

Comment: Don't you know in the test, that which sequence, you want to run?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `uvm_event`.  The name of an `uvm_event` is unique, you can use `uvm_event_pool` to get the instance of the `uvm_event` with the same name.  If an uvm_event of the name does not exist, uvm_event_pool will create one when `get()` is called the first time.

Both the main sequence and the other sequence get an `uvm_event` with the same name.  The main sequence calls `.wait_trigger()` and the other sequence calls `.trigger()` of the `uvm_event`.